# Application fails visualizing more than 600 Images

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, canvas

I wrote a WPF app that should swap (fast) between a large set of images (600+, 190Kb average size), but I'm finding some difficulties.

```
    private int appendImages(Canvas c, int start, int end)
    {
        int tot = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            //bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(appFolder+@"/"+imgFolder+"/"+filename(i)+".jpg");
            bi.EndInit();

            Image img = new Image
            {
                Width = imgWidth,
                Height = imgHeight,
                Source = bi,
                Name = name(i),
                Visibility = i == startImg ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden
            };

            c.Children.Add(img);
            tot++;
        }
   }
```

Apparently the inizialization is fine, but if I try to swap the images like this:

```
    private void changeImageTo(int n)
    {
        Image img = findImage(n);
        Image old = findImage(prevImg);
        if (img != null)
        {
            img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            if (old != null && old != img)
                old.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            prevImg = n;
        }
    }
```

..then the app shows the first 200/300 images (depending on the sources I use), and the others are just empty/blank (i can see the canvas underneath).

I suspect it's a memory issue, but I'm not really sure what causes it.

By the way, if I uncomment the commented line (BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad) sometimes I get a vshost error when launching the app.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated, since I couldn't find anything useful browsing around.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're loading all the images at once, and putting them into WinForms/WPF controls. That is a very bad idea with that many images, as each one takes resources even if it's not shown.

Rough back of the envelope calculation, assuming 640x480 images, 24bpp being the native GDI+ format, shows a bit over 2gb for loading all the images at once, and that would, of course, increase exponentially with image size.

What I would do instead, is have only one Image. Move the actual image loading code into your `changeImageTo` function, build the file name based on `n`, and set the loaded image to the Image there.

Comment: Hi Matt and thanks for the reply.
I forgot to mention (and now edited the question) I'm working with WPF and the rough size of each JPG is about 190Kb. 

I tried using just one Image and changing the source of it on MouseMove (that's what triggers the swapping) but it's too slow to work properly.. I guess with your solution would be almost the same, but I'm giving a try, just in case.. (:

Comment: I have to admit it's either faster or I made some mistakes with my previous attempt. In any case, your solution works quite fine (even if a bit slower than I hoped for), so again, thanks!! (: